# how to send email using djnago

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a situation where using API android app will POST the user Data to my django website and a entry is created in my backend .I want to send email to the user after the entry has been created in django.
I have created a indicator which will get true when Data is POST.
ANy suggestion how to use that indicator for sending email to every new entry created .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Django does the work for you :

```
  from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

But you need to setup your email service such as Gmail or Sendgrid